# $\int_0^\infty dt e^{-pt} \frac{e^{-x^2/2t}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} = \frac1{\sqrt{2p}} e^{-\sqrt{2px^2}}$ for $p \in \mathbb R_+, x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, integration

> (Cinlar, probability and stochastics p.395) $\int_0^\infty dt e^{-pt} \frac{e^{-x^2/2t}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} = \frac1{\sqrt{2p}} e^{-\sqrt{2px^2}}$ for $p \in \mathbb R_+, x \in \mathbb R$.

I want to verify this equation. The l.h.s. can be rewritten as
$$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty dt e^{-pt +x^2/2t} t^{-1/2}.$$
The integral looks like a Gamma function with 1/2. I guess the next step is to find a smart way to use a substitution for the exponent $-pt + x^2/2t$, but I am stuck here. I would appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integral solution, kind of Laplace transfom $\int_{0}^{T_0} \frac{e^{-st-\frac{x^2}{4t}}}{\sqrt{\pi t}}dt$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479566/integral-solution-kind-of-laplace-transfom-int-0t-0-frace-st-fracx)